# Cocoapods updates to newer version than specified in Podfile

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I have the following line in my Podfile

```
pod 'Instabug', '~> 3.2'
```

When running **pod update** the version 3.4.6 of instabug is downloaded.

```
Installing Instabug 3.4.6 (was 3.2)
```

Why does this happen? How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. From ["The Podfile" Cocoapods doc](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html):

> In addition to the logic operators CocoaPods has an optimisic operator ~>:
>
> '~> 0.1.2' Version 0.1.2 and the versions up to 0.2, not including 0.2 and higher
>
> '~> 0.1' Version 0.1 and the versions up to 1.0, not including 1.0 and higher
>
> '~> 0' Version 0 and higher, this is basically the same as not having it.

So you can write

```
pod 'Instabug', '~> 3.2.0'
```

to get the behavior you expected. This will get the latest version of the pod, up to (but not including) `3.3.0`.